# FluentValidation set custom validator for collections multiple levels deep

Tags: asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I have an entity structure as follows (parent first)

`Training` has many
`Module`s has many
`Phase`s has many
`Question`s

Only `Training` and `Question` have fields to validate.
I have a separate validator for `Training` and `Question`

Inside my `Training` validator how can I set the custom validator when my collection is this many levels deep?
Something like

`RuleFor(x=>x.Modules).RuleFor(x=>x.Phases).RuleForEach(x=>x.Questions).SetValidator(new QuestionValidator())`

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ChildRules` and `RuleForEach` to validate nested property:

```
public class TrainingValidator : AbstractValidator<Training>
    {
        public TrainingValidator()
        {
             //validate property in Training
             RuleFor(x => x.Name).Length(5,8);

             //validate property in Question
             RuleForEach(a => a.Modules).ChildRules(b => b.RuleForEach(c => c.Phases).ChildRules(d=>d.RuleForEach(e=>e.Questions).SetValidator(new QuestionValidator())));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @americanslon, wait for your response. If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer? If not, could you please follow up to let me know?